# Can't set password for newly added linux user

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I used this cmd to add a new user and a new group.

```
# groupadd lfs
# useradd -s /bin/bash -g lfs -m -k /dev/null lfs
# su lfs
$ passwd
Changing password for lfs.
(current) UNIX password:
```

Then no matter what password I typed (my root passwd, or a completely new one), they all failed.

```
$ passwd
Changing password for lfs.
(current) UNIX password: 
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

What's wrong with my setting ? How can I set the passwd successfully ? Thanks !

Comment: Should this be on Super User?

Comment: yeah, I made a mistake, the initial passwd has to be set in root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Become root and then change the password. It won't ask for current password.

```
su
passwd lfs
```

Comment: Oh yeah, passwd should be used in root. Thanks !

Comment: passwd must work also for normal users.